# CSS to hide all elements except the specified

Tags: jquery, css

Is there a CSS equivalent for the following jQuery code:

```
$('#myElement').parents().siblings().hide()
$('#myElement').siblings().hide()
```

This does exactly what I want by hiding everything except parents and descendants of a given element.  I want to create a `@media print` CSS rule that has the same effect.

Comment: Do you have some HTML code?

Comment: if a parent is hidden, so are the children

Comment: Not sure there's a parent selector in CSS atm, another way would be to have print class on the parent of what you want to show and in the print css hide everything else. Seeing your html might help too.

Comment: There isn't a parent selector yet, @theatlasroom. :( Still waiting!

Comment: If you are familiar with [Beaker Notebook](http://beakernotebook.com/), the HTML is whatever is inside an HTML cell.  The purpose of this is to be able to print a single HTML cell without all the Beaker stuff around it.  Here's [an example](https://pub.beakernotebook.com/publications/7fdcaaa6-fb83-11e5-9212-0797fdc961bc).  HTML cells have a red icon with letters "Ht" inside.  In this sample notebook, you'd want to isolate and print element with `id="fdg"`

Comment: Any reason you can't just use the jQuery code you posted? If not, then another option could be to use jQuery to add custom classes (say some thing like .printable) to the elements you want to print and then in the print css hide anything without the .printable class.

Comment: @theatlasroom: I'm looking for a pure CSS solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could try and achieve this with the level 3 selector pseudo-class :not(), but the browser support seems poor: [caniuse.com :not() selector](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Anot()).

**EDIT:**

I'm assuming you can add a different class to the parent element containing your #myElement.

Alternatively, you can target all tags just in case,  like `<p>, <section>` etc outside a `<div>`, changing it like this: `.container :not(.parent):not(.different)`

```css
.container div:not(.parent):not(.different) {
  display: none;
}
.children,
.parent-sibling {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.parent-sibling {
  background-color: blue;
}
.different {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="children"></div>
    <div class="children different"></div>
    <div class="children"></div>
    <div class="children"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent-sibling">
    <div class="children"></div>
    <div class="children"></div>
    <div class="children"></div>
    <div class="children"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent-sibling"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make custom css class for hiding divs then with jquery show them before print example :

css

```
.hidden{display:none;}
```

jquery:

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
$('.hidden').show();
});
```

that will be more easy for you.

Comment: I don't have control over most of the scaffolding HTML.